# Maintained Dart ORMs (specially for mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, orm, dart

Is there any ORM currently in active maintenance? I found these ones, but, or they are only for PostgreSQL, or they are not maintained anymore.

- [objectory](https://github.com/vadimtsushko/objectory) : One year since last commit and it looks like they moved to PostgreSQL (before they were using mongoDB)
- [angel-dart](https://github.com/angel-dart/orm) : It only support PostgreSql
- [aqueduct](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct) : It only support PostgreSql
- [dartORM](https://github.com/ustims/DartORM): Looks really good, but last commit was 2 years ago :(

Is there any other library I should check out?

thanks in advance

Comment: related https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/issues/228

Answer (score 2):

The ORM for Angel only supports PostgreSQL, but Angel also has support for MongoDB and RethinkDB. It’s also straightforward to add support for another database using the Service API.

I have considered porting the ORM generators to NoSQL databases, but typically I’ve seen ORM mostly used for relational databases.

If you combine Angel’s MongoDB services with package:angel_serialize, you can interact with your database using Dart’s strong typing. There’s also the angel_relations package you can use, to simulate relationships between different services, even though their underlying implementation might be NoSQL.https://github.com/angel-dart/mongo
https://github.com/angel-dart/serialize
https://github.com/angel-dart/relations

Comment: Really interesting libraries! I will definitely take a look at them, but I was looking for a more immediate solution with zero implementation and zero maintenance. Thank you for the suggestion though, I will consider it if I don't find anything else.

Comment: Ah, not sure if there is anything available like that for Dart. Perhaps ask in the Gitter chats.